# My website was attacked with malicious JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security

Recently my website was put on Google's blacklist because someone placed a malicious snippet of code in my Google analytic tracking code.
The suspicious snippet picked up by Google is:

```
script src = http://layole dot ru/follow2
```

I was wondering if someone more qualified could tell me what this attacker was trying to achieve and what this code does.

Comment: Why don't you post it here so that we did not have to go to your site?

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to click on the malicious link you posted to be sure, but from the one sentence of information you posted this is likely a cross site scripting attack where there is a vulnerability that allows a user to get other users to run a different script potentially allowing them to gather sensitive information. Generic answer for a generic question I suppose. 
see the wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting